# How to reduce 24V to 0V-5V variable through a pot with an output current of 3amp?

Tags: power, dc, converter, 5v, 24v

I want to build a 5v variable PSU. I found one on ebay but the output current is not good for my application, 10mA.

[image]

Comment: This needs a lot more information to be answerable. A potentiometer is about the worst solution here, for numerous reasons.

Comment: You can buy DCDC converters that do this for a few dollars online.  If those don't work for you, explain why and what special thing you need.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately, I don't have much. Machine i'm working with had a Japanase custom made power supply to that and it went bad after couple years. The purpose was to send 0-5v signal to PLCs cards. Only thing I can tell if that the current output was 2.1a and the it used 2K pot to regulate the output.

Comment: You mention variable, but also mention "reduce 24 to 5V" which doesn't sound very variable. You also mention both 3 A and 10 mA. What are your actual needs?

Comment: input is 24vdc fix. Variable output 0-5vdc. Output current minimum 2.1a, preferably 3a

Comment: It sounds as though you are confusing the potentiometer (which **controls** the setpoint of a variable voltage power supply) with the power supply itself.

Comment: If there's 2-3 Amps of current, then it's not a signal for a PLC, it's a power supply for something that needs a variable voltage. I wonder what that is, and where that current requirement comes from.

Comment: This one will be perfect, but it's only 10ma. https://www.amazon.com/Voltage-Generator-Module-Adjustable-Quantity/dp/B08TW8RGPN/ref=pd_lpo_sccl_3/131-3359206-1285865?pd_rd_w=dNoF6&content-id=amzn1.sym.116f529c-aa4d-4763-b2b6-4d614ec7dc00&pf_rd_p=116f529c-aa4d-4763-b2b6-4d614ec7dc00&pf_rd_r=VRS9MBJ525NFG7DAQDBV&pd_rd_wg=N7Ubx&pd_rd_r=790c3bd1-32d6-4a3b-870e-1acc4593feab&pd_rd_i=B08TW8RGPN&psc=1

Comment: Power requirement it may be because that unit is a bit far from all PLCs that it's supplying power to. To compensate the lost in the long wires.

Comment: Thanks everyone for replying. I found an alternative option on Amazon.

Comment: Amazon might not be the place you'd usually buy electronics from if you need them to be reliable…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting generic variable supply to go down to 0V on the  output is tricky, this is because the feedback is referenced against a fixed voltage, so to get zero out you need to feed the fixed voltage in to the feedback.

so to do this you need to offset the feedback signal by some offset without dominating it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f83sfa.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

here I'm using an LM317 to make a voltage slightly higher than the output voltage so that it can be fed back allowing selection of voltages below 1.25v .  R2 limits the selectable output range to about 0-5.1V

on a generic adjustable DC-DC module the feedback pin is connected to the middle pin ot the adjustment potentiometer, so rip the potentiometer off (trying to unsolder is hard) the de-solder the pins and connect a circuit like above to where the middle pin was.

The LM317 won't be making much heat so a TO92 model can be used (like LM317LZ)

this way you'll be able to use $1 XL4015 buck modules as the DC-DC converters and still get the full 0-5V potentiometer adjustment range.

Comment: thanks, I'll try that. However, I ordered a 120/220Vac input volts to 0-5vdc variable power supply, 60amp output.

Comment: What should be output current for that diagram, or it's based one DC-DC buck I chose?

Comment: yes it's based on the device you choose,  XL4005 or XL4015 based buck converters cost about a dollar (depending where you shop)  and will go to 5A peak and have no trouble with 3A continuous

Answer (score -1):

Find an LM338K IC in the TO-3 case and use it.

Comment: a power supply capable of 0V to 5V is needed.  LM338 won't go that low.